# Removing duplicates while preserving values

Tags: r

I have a tabular table example here:

```
Jerry 2
John 3
Mark 4
John 1
Kevin 10
```

I want to remove duplicate entries, John in this case, but want to preserve the value and add them up. Not sure if that made sense, but it should look like:

```
Jerry 2
John 4
Mark 4
Kevin 10
```

Any ideas of how to do this in R? I know how to remove duplicates but not add up all of the duplicate values.

Thanks.

Comment: You can delete your post if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `aggregate` and specify the `FUN` as `sum`

```
aggregate(col2~Name, df1, FUN = sum)
#    Name col2
#1 Jerry    2
#2  John    4
#3 Kevin   10
#4  Mark    4
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(col2 = sum(col2)), by = Name]
#    Name col2
#1: Jerry    2
#2:  John    4
#3:  Mark    4
#4: Kevin   10
```

---

Or use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(col2 = sum(col2))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Jerry", "John", "Mark", "John", "Kevin"
 ), col2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 10L)), .Names = c("Name", "col2"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: This is an obvious dupe, why not just hammer?

Comment: @zx8754  It already got dupe tagged by DavidArenburg

Comment: I was looking for an answer but wasn't using the right key words, so I did not find the duplicate post. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Of course I **noticed** it before I posted that comment. Point is you must already realize some posts are 100% dupe why post an answer? And you know very well how dupe hammering works.

Comment: @zx8754  WHen I search for dupes, I will always hammer with dupe.  But, in most cases, getting the right dupes may be a challenge or I type the answer.

Comment: @zx8754 Forgot about the other important issue.  At workplace, if I use LAN, I won't get google, and if I use wireless, SO website have problems.  So, I normally use LAN connection.

Comment: I understand you might have reasons, but once it is established that it is 100% dupe, why not delete? If dupe target doesn't fully address the question, then why not add a new answer at the targeted post? Anyway, it is up to you.

Comment: @zx8754 I would say that dupe answers will make it more easy to find with search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to `aggregate` is `ddply` from `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, c("Name"), function(x) sum(x$Value))


#   Name V1
#1 Jerry  2
#2  John  4
#3 Kevin 10
#4  Mark  4
```